# Shift, CMD, Option and Alt disable my left/right mouse clicks

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, mouse

I've noticed that for a few days now, on my computer running Mojave 10.14.6, that if I hold any of the modifier keys down, I lose the ability to left or right click, preventing me from using any application that uses the modifier+click combo or selecting multiple items in a list  that aren't right next to each other

I use a Corsair K70 Mk.2 keyboard and Corsair M65 mouse with the ckb-next driver, the Magic Trackpad doesn't work for this either.

Comment: As it's not a standard Apple keyboard, the first test would be to swap to one.

Comment: You’ve introduced not only a different keyboard but, as you state, a different driver.  Boot to safe mode with a standard keyboard and see if things work or not.  If they do, the issue is with your config.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Allan, however booting into safe mode did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply fixed this by nuking my drive and reinstalling. Doing a simple in-place reinstall didn't help.